# Drupal absolute path for everything for one page

Tags: drupal-7, content-type, absolute-path

There is one page (content type => basic page) where all links must be absolute, not relative.
It is a template used by a 3rd party.
If relative, for ex. the css is not loaded.

Howto?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

1. global $base_url
2. `drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME_NAME');`
3. It returns the path without slashes in front or after.
   That's the type *first*, then the project name
   drupal_get_path('module', 'name_of_module');
   I reverse that enough (and then get confused as to why it isn't working) that i felt it worth documenting here, so the 'doh!' moment of realization comes sooner...

The valid types are as listed:

module

theme

profile

theme_engine

I can't think of any others and i can't even think of a reason to use the last one.